# How do I cleanly pass a react component to another component deep down in the component heirarchy?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have React + Redux + Typescript application composed of a map, several charts, and a series of modal dialogs (one of which is a print form). The [presentational and container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) are composed as follows.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐  
│ app.tsx                                  │
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│  │ modalsContainer.tsx                 │ │
│  │  ┌────────────────────────────────┐ │ │ 
│  │  │ printModal.tsx                 │ │ │
│  │  │  ┌───────────────────────────┐ │ │ │
│  │  │  │ printFormContainer.tsx    │ │ │ │
│  │  │  │    const mergeProps(...); │ │ │ │
│  │  │  └───────────────────────────┘ │ │ │
│  │  └────────────────────────────────┘ │ │ 
│  └─────────────────────────────────────┘ │
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│  │ mapContainer.tsx                    │ │
│  │  ┌────────────────────────────────┐ │ │ 
│  │  │ map.tsx                        │ │ │
│  │  │     private map:EsriMap        │ │ │
│  │  └────────────────────────────────┘ │ │ 
│  └─────────────────────────────────────┘ │ 
│  ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐ │
│  │ dashboard.tsx                       │ │
│  │  ┌────────────────────────────────┐ │ │ 
│  │  │ charts.tsx                     │ │ │
│  │  └────────────────────────────────┘ │ │ 
│  └─────────────────────────────────────┘ │ 
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The print form allows the user to print the charts and map to a pdf. A web request is made for report to be printed based on the selected charts and the current map. The logic for this is set up in `const mergeProps(...);` shown below:

```
const mergeProps = (stateProps: any, dispatchProps: any, ownProps: any): any => {
    return {
        fetchReport: (title: string, summary: string, includeMap: boolean) => {
            if(includeMap) {
               // fetch map image
               // need access to mapcontainer /map / esrimap here
            }

            // ... fetch report ...
        },
        close: dispatchProps.close
    };
};
```

This mostly works but I have yet to include the map image in the report. In order to generate an image of the map I need to execute a [PrintTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/printtask-amd.html). One of the parameters for the print task is the esri map object. However, from mergeProps I do not have access to the MapContainer or Map components. If I did, I could add a `Print():Promise<any>` function to perform the task and return the image.

I really want to avoid globals. Other capabilities in the future may also require access to the map. I also want to avoid passing components as props so deeply through the stack. I read a bit about [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), but that seems to be highly not recommended.

How do I cleanly pass a component to another deep down in the stack?

Comment: You can put the component on your redux state and grab it with `connect`. react-redux uses context by the way

Comment: Why not just fire off the PrintTask action inside your Map Component that has access to the EsirMap object,  Pass the dispatch action into the map component so you can modify application state.

Comment: @Gamak, I had considered that but even so the `MapComponent` would still need to be passed down through the layers to `mergeProps` in order to execute that function.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

First, putting anything non-serializable (such as a component or a function) into the Redux state is generally a bad idea (per https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state ).

Second, why is the callback logic currently being defined in `mergeProps`?  That option should really only be a fallback of last resort.  It's better to define callbacks separately and pass them to the component. I have some discussion and examples of that at http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/ .

Following with that, I believe the simplest approach would be to define a separate callback function that takes the needed flags *and* the EsriMap object as parameters, and pass that function as a prop to the Map component.

Comment: The logic is currently in `mergeProps` to connect the `print report` button click to the `fetchReport` function. I needed access to some state (such as as list of charts to print) to generate a report web request. I need to generate a map image for said request; that can only be done with a print task that requires `map` as a parameter. However `mapContainer` is not available from my `printFormContainer`. I need access to state and a component elsewhere in the component tree. FWIW, the print report capability does not modify state. Action creators are typically used to modify state, right?

Comment: As an alternative to `mergeProps`, you could have the component retrieve the necessary data in `mapState`, and then grab the value from props and pass it to the external callback function.  You could also define the callback function / action creator as a "thunk", which would give it access to `getState()`.

Comment: Doesn't the initial problem remain though, that is, callback function still does not have access to the required `map` parameter?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. Just to check: you're not actually concerned about the `mapContainer` _component_, you're trying to access the `map` instance _inside_ that component?  You might want to read through this article on component communication approaches: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/ .  Kinda sounds like either the `map` shouldn't live inside of the `mapContainer`, or you might want to consider using a shared event bus to trigger the printing.

Comment: That's a great reference, thanks. The solution we're going to go with for the moment is to pass the mapComponent down through via props using rest parameters. Rest and spread operators are supported as of TypeScript 2.1. Not quite what I was hoping for but it does simplify passing down props to children several layers down.